# "options.php" not found

Tags: functions, theme-development, themes, wp-admin, options

I am making a Wordpress theme with a custom admin page. What I did to make it save the settings was this:

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">
```

When I hit the submit button, I got an error message saying that "options.php" was not found. I attempted to change the general settings and it worked. It was just with my settings page.

Thanks!

EDIT:
I just found something on the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting) about this. But I have no idea what it means. It is at the "Notes" section. If someone could help that would be great!

My code:http://pastebin.com/bvXcXhCQ

Comment: I'm not sure why it said options.php not found, but that code isn't going to work - `type="text"` is for `<input>` elements, not the `<form>` element, and the location to load should go in the `action` attribute not the `method`. Where did you get this code from?

Comment: Oh, oops. I didn't see my code and I mistaken the type thing. I updated it.

Comment: Where is the form getting added? Is it in a settings page, registered with the Settings API? Please show your code so we have more context and aren't left guessing what you're trying to do.

Comment: @morganestes I updated my question with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @LupuAndrei said, we lack of details, especially the code where you call you form from.

But I suspect, again like @LupuAndrei said, you might not be calling the `settings_fields`, `do_settings_fields` or `do_settings_sections`  correctly.

On the function where you build your form, try something like this

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">
   <table class="form-table">
      <?php 

      settings_fields( 'animated-settings-group' ); // This will output the nonce, action, and option_page fields for a settings page.
      do_settings_sections( 'hoogleyboogley_animated' ); // This prints out the actual sections containing the settings fields for the page in parameter 

      ?>
    </table>

  <?php submit_button(); ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks a lot of details which could clarify the source of the problem. For example, this error could be also triggered by a wrong call to an `add_settings_field` function or how `settings_fields` looks there. These things are essential.

I could try a blind shot and believe that the [register_setting](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting) function has a different `$option_group` than `$option_name`. Try to make the first two parameters to be exactly the same.

Also, you need to take care of your fields. [add_settings_field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field) those params must match the `register_setting` ones

Now if you are really unlucky you could have a problem with `whitelist_options` filter or some plugin you have installed may crash this.

Personally, I've written a [story](http://andrei-lupu.com/programming/error-options-page-not-found/) about how I've got this error and how I've solved it, but it was an isolated case

Comment: I read your page. But I couldn't figure out what you meant by it. I started off with a fresh Wordpress install, so no plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your form code as:

`<form name="form1" method="POST" action="options.php">`

Type is not a Form attribute. To know more form attribute please see: [From attribute](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_form_tag.htm)

Comment: I tried that. It still says options.php not found.

Comment: @HoogleyBoogley: Update you permalink structure remove name="form1" from the code above. Your form should work after then

Comment: Yes, I did that. Nothing is working. My error is: ERROR: options page not found.